# function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a rectangle and I'm passing all the arguments to the function but it doesn't work, I tried also to change the code but it doesn't work.

first attempt (he don't take the color, the thickness and the lineType)

`cv2.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_4)`

second attempt I declared them before (now I get the argument problem)

`cv2.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, color, thickness, lineType)`

full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


haystack_img = cv2.imread('screen.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
needle_img = cv2.imread('mr_karate.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

result = cv2.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

needle_w = needle_img[1]
needle_h = needle_img[0]

top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + needle_w, top_left[1] + needle_h)

color = (0, 255, 0)
thickness = 2
lineType = cv2.LINE_4

cv2.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, color, thickness, lineType)


cv2.imshow('Result', haystack_img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

please I need help, I'm stuck on this and I don't know where is the problem

Comment: What's the exact traceback of the error?

Comment: TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Comment: I suspect that you've run into [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15465) (which I found by entering your error message in a search engine; it seems common). Make sure that your coordinates are integers.

Comment: Is there a line reference in the code telling you which function is complaining?  I'm looking through your snippet and I don't see any functions that you've called with 4 arguments.  I see 2, 2, 3, 6, 2 ...

Comment: is the line 21, where I use the rectangle function which sintax is this cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

Comment: To expand on what molbdnilo said, try printing out the values of `top_left` and `bottom_right`.  They should be 2-tuples of ints (not floats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bottom_right** value is incorrect.

```
(array([[ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       ...,
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       ...,
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255],
       [ 29,  29,  29, 255]], dtype=uint8))
```

**bottom_right** should be like (20,20)

```
bottom_right = (20,20)
```

Comment: I resolved the issue, you were right I missed the ".shape" on the needle_w and needle_h